# Subquery with TOP performing poorly

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Ok I have a performance problem in SQL function. I have query like this:

```
SELECT
    Number,
    (SELECT TOP 1 Value 
     FROM Table_B 
     WHERE Table_B.Number = Table_A.Number 
     ORDER BY ID DESC)
FROM 
    Table_A
```

I want see all records from `Table_A` with the TOP 1 record from `Table_B`

Comment: Use JOIN instead of corelated subquery.

Comment: Define "performance problem" with actual numbers and statistics. Perhaps search "first in group" for an alternative approach (which might or might not be an improvement). Selecting all rows from any table is usually rare and i'll guess that you obfuscated your schema so that gives no clues what you are actually doing.

Comment: Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an _actual execution plan_ in your question. Perhaps you just need to index `Table_B` on `( Number, ID desc )`.

Comment: We cannot properly answer this without a query plan, please share it, along with table and index definitions

Answer (score 3):

You may try adding the following index to `Table_B`:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx_b ON Table_B (Number, ID) INCLUDE (Value);
```

This index should let the `Number` lookup be fast, and should allow the first `Value`, as sorted by the `ID`, to be found.  We include `Value` at the end of the index since it is used in the select, but not needed in the index itself.

Comment: i have that index

Answer (score 1):

Use ROW_NUMBER() for serializing value with id desc and then LEFT JOIN main table with matching number and retrieve only first record from subquery result. LEFT JOIN is used here because table_B have no value for a number but as per requirement corresponding value of table_A must come.

```
-- SQL Server
SELECT a.Number
     , b.value
FROM Table_A a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Number, ID, value
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Number, ID ORDER BY id DESC) row_num
           FROM Table_B) b         
       ON a.Number = b.Number
      AND b.row_num = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the "first in group" method that SMor mentions:

```
WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT a.Number,
          b.Value, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.Number ORDER BY b.ID DESC) AS rn
   FROM Table_A a
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_B b ON a.Number = b.Number
)
SELECT Number, Value
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE_Table_B
AS(
    SELECT
        x.[ID],
        x.[Value],
        x.[Number]
    FROM(
        SELECT
            [ID]
            [Value],
            [Number],
            DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY [Number] ORDER BY [ID] DESC) AS [Ranking]
        FROM Table_B
    ) AS x
    WHERE (1=1)
        AND x.[Ranking] = 1
)

SELECT
    a.[Number],
    b.[Value] 
FROM Table_A AS a

LEFT JOIN CTE_Table_B AS b
    ON b.[Number] = a.[Number]
```

Comment: I think DENSE_RANK will create duplicates in the output here if there are ties for first

Comment: I think you are right. If there is no clear order, then it is probably better to work with ROW_NUMBER().

Answer (score 0):

How about just using CROSS APPLY (assuming there will always be a match - if not use OUTER APPLY):

```
SELECT
    Number, tb.Value
FROM 
    Table_A
CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT TOP 1 Value 
     FROM Table_B 
     WHERE Table_B.Number = Table_A.Number 
     ORDER BY ID DESC) AS tb
```